# installing daylerees color scheme for vim using vundle - mac os x

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I installed Vundle to my /Users/name directory (ie /Users/name/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim) a while ago, and set up a .vimrc file in my root directory which has the following:

```
set nocompatible
filetype off

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'

Bundle 'daylerees/colour-schemes', { "rtp": "vim/" }
colorscheme frontier

call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on
```

I ran `:PluginInstall` as suggested and it says everything has been installed, but I get a "color scheme frontier not found" error everytime I open vim.

This is as far as I've done, am I missing any steps?

Comment: i've added the vim file of frontier.vim to /.vim/colors/. Now i don't get the not found error, but the color scheme doesn't show up

Comment: Are you sure syntax highlighting is on? `:syntax on`

Comment: just to add, if you want to enable syntax by default (without having to do so every time you open a new file), include 'syntax on' in your .vimrc file

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line after the `filetype` line:

```
syntax on
```

And move your `colorscheme frontier` line anywhere *after* the `call vundle#end()` line.

Comment: I've done so, but the theme is still the default one. I can see the highlighting but that is not of the frontier theme

Comment: I've updated my Bundle declaration to the one referred to in the github page

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be mixing the old and new Vundle syntaxes. Instead of

```
Bundle 'daylerees/colour-schemes', { "rtp": "vim/" }
```

try

```
Plugin 'daylerees/colour-schemes', { 'rtp': 'vim/' }
```

Note the use of single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: OK. On the other side of the coin—are you sure you’re using the latest version of Vundle?